# Getting selected vue value into data return

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently using a vue datepicker which, when a date is selected, shows pickedValue as the value for the selected date in vue developer tools:

```
<div v-cloak v-if="isScheduledTask">
            <datepicker value="" name="pickedValue" id="pickedValue" ></datepicker>
</div>
```

Trying to set the pickedValue to a variable in my data return (i need the picked value to be submitted with other data here) as a $ref is breaking the page. If I change this to just datepicker.pickedValue then it's undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

```
data() {
    return {
       pickedValue: this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very bad pattern, but you have no choice working with library that does not emit **ANY** events.

**DON'T DO IT EVER AGAIN!!!**

```html
<datepicker ref="datepicker" @click.native="method"></datepicker>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    value: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  method() {
    this.value = this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `v-model` directive to bind your datepicker to that data property `pickedValue` as follows :

```
<div v-cloak v-if="isScheduledTask">
  <datepicker value="" name="pickedValue" v-model="pickedValue" ></datepicker>
</div>
```

script :

```
data() {
    return {
       pickedValue: ''
    }
 }
```